# Getting initiator of XXX-xsrfstatemanager.js file using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-authentication

In order to triage a problem with a web browser I am trying to determine the initiator of the **XXX-xsrfstatemanager.js** file (the XXX part seems to be something dynamic like a nonce) that occurs as part of a Google Authentication flow (using OAuth).

When I use Chrome developer tools, it says the below URL is the initiator:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?approval_state=%21Ch[REDACTED]Q%E2%88%99AJ[REDACTED]xq&as=-aBk[REDACTED]

Looking at the result of the above page see a lot of Javascript, but the string "xsrfstatemanager" is nowhere to be found, nor do I see any other javascript pages being included. Unless there is some really cryptic code that is somehow building this URL, the call is actually coming from some other page.

Does anyone know how I can get the 'real' initiator? Or if the above URL might be correct, if I can get more information like what exact line number of the file initiated the call?

By the way, while I edited the above URL for security reasons, if you go to (for example) www.quora.com and quick "continue with google" it is easy to see the flow in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow includes a redirection, which is why you cannot see the source code that initiates/references that script.
If you view the source of the original URL that is opened when you click on "Continue with Google", you will see the `<script src>` that references it. This works in Chrome and probably Safari -
`view-source:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%2Fwww.quora.com%3Fid%3Dauth488109&response_type=code%20permission%20id_token&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&client_id=917071888555.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&prompt=select_account&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com&gsiwebsdk=2`

From the source code -

```
<script src='https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/532969778-xsrfstatemanager.js' nonce="IgiKmQiLZIHDwGvce7/q6Q"></script>
```

You can also use tools like Fiddler to see the source code of the redirect, or check "Preserve log" in the Network panel of the Developer Tools feature of Chrome, or by going to the original URL with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am having trouble with some of the things you suggested. When I check "preserve log" and try in Chrome developer tools I don't seem to see the "Forwarding..." page. Also, when I try disabling JS on Chrome and click on "Continue with Google" link, I get "https://www.quora.com/#", and the source to that doesn't have the "Forwarding..." content either. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Locksleyu - enable "Preserve log" and in the settings, you can enable "Auto-open DevTools for popups" and click on the "Continue with Google" button. In the new Developer Tools that opens, you can see the redirection (the first entry in the network panel). You can then take its URL (it is a static URL, at least in the Quora case). You can then open it in a tab, either by prepending view-source: to it, or by opening a new tab, opening the Developer Tools and disabling JavaScript in the settings and then navigating to the URL.